# How to pass parameters to a Button click

Tags: c#, winforms, button, parameters

I have a program that asks questions and I would like it to keep track of how many questions the user has failed, questions are generated at the click of a button and I want it to keep track of if the user has been asked a question so it can mark them as not answering it.

If the user clicks the button to generate another question it will know that the question wasn't answered and increment the counter. It currently gives the error message

> No overload for 'NextGasQuestion_Click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'

Here is the handler code:

```
private void NextGasQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e,bool QuestionAnswered,int GasQuestionsFailed)
{
    if (QuestionAnswered == false)
     {
        GasQuestionsFailed++;
     }
}    // Added by edit
```

Comment: You can't modify the parameters of WinForm event handlers. You'll need to find another way to figure out which button was pressed and why.

Comment: What you're looking for is "User Validation", which is a whole topic onto itself.

Comment: Where do you getting `QuestionAnswered` and `GasQuestionsFailed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass parameters to a button click function but can make a global variable that is valid in your button click and other scopes:

for example:

```
bool QuestionAnswered  = true;  // it is outside the button click or other functions

void SomeMethod()
{
    QuestionAnswered = false;
}


private void NextGasQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!QuestionAnswered)
     {
        GasQuestionsFailed++;
     }
}
```

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yes I know, I just thought it was the default signature, I just copied it from question ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to pass something into the button event you can use the `Tag` property on the button.  You can access this inside of the event handler by doing something along these lines.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn == null) return;

    var yourValue = btn.Tag as YourType;
    if (yourValue != null)
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

As others have states you should probably just create a variable on the form and increment that value instead of maintaining state on the button its self.